# How to extract all the column name from the required table by Excel(or maybe python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel

Now I have table1 as below:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First | Second | Second |
| Second | Third | Forth |

I now want to output a list(The first column has already known):

| First | A |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Second | A | B | C |
| Thrid | B |  |  |
| Forth | C |  |  |

How can I output this using Excel(or maybe python, if much easier)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I prefer GordonAitchJay's answer as it uses an existing library, most (if not all) spreadsheet editors can export sheets in .csv format (comma-separated values). From there you could read the first line containing the column names, and split on commas.

Off the top of my head it should look something like this:

```
columnNames = None
with open(filePath, "r", encoding="utf-8") as contents:
    columnNames = contents.getlines()[0].split(",")    # Or maybe "readlines()"

# Do your magic.
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with Python and the [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) package. The code below reads an existing spreadsheet `table1.xlsx`, and creates a new spreadsheet `table1_columns.xlsx` listing the unique values and the columns they were found in. With your input, the code produces your output.

```py
import os
from collections import defaultdict
import openpyxl

input_filename = r"table1.xlsx"
output_filename = r"table1_columns.xlsx"

# Read the input spreadsheet file
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(input_filename)

# Use the first spreadsheet in the workbook
ws = wb.worksheets[0]

# Iterate over every cell in each column, and read the values into a dict 
# which has a default value of an empty set.
# The keys are the cell values, e.g. "First"
# The values are sets of column letters the cell value was found in, e.g. {"A"}
values = defaultdict(set)
for cells in ws.iter_cols():
    for cell in cells:
        values[cell.value].add(cell.column_letter)

# Create a new spreadsheet
wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
ws = wb.active

# Iterate over the dict, writing each value and its column letters to a new row
for row_num, (value, column_letters) in enumerate(values.items(), start=1):
    # The first column is always the value, e.g. "First"
    ws.cell(row=row_num, column=1).value = value
    
    # As sets are an unordered data type, it first needs to be sorted. If not, 
    # the second row could be "Second B A C" instead of "Second A B C"
    column_letters = sorted(column_letters)
    for column_num, column_letter in enumerate(column_letters, start=2):
        ws.cell(row=row_num, column=column_num).value = column_letter

# Save the spreadsheet to disk
wb.save(output_filename)

# Launch the new spreadsheet
os.startfile(output_filename)
```